# How to load only ActiveModel validations?

Tags: validation, activemodel

I want to use `ActiveModel::Validations` in a small Roda app, and I really want to keep it small and I would like to avoid loading the entirety of `ActiveModel` in it. Is there a way to require only `ActiveModel::Validations` ?

At least with `activemodel-4.2.6.` an attempt to `require 'active_model/validations'` results with

```
/home/bbozo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activemodel-4.2.6/lib/active_model/validations/format.rb:4:in `<module:Validations>': uninitialized constant ActiveModel::Validations::EachValidator (NameError)
        from /home/bbozo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activemodel-4.2.6/lib/active_model/validations/format.rb:3:in `<module:ActiveModel>'
        from /home/bbozo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activemodel-4.2.6/lib/active_model/validations/format.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/bbozo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activemodel-4.2.6/lib/active_model/validations.rb:405:in `require'
        from /home/bbozo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activemodel-4.2.6/lib/active_model/validations.rb:405:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /home/bbozo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activemodel-4.2.6/lib/active_model/validations.rb:405:in `each'
        from /home/bbozo/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/gems/activemodel-4.2.6/lib/active_model/validations.rb:405:in `<top (required)>'
```

Hmff, OK, writing this question I found the solution ^_^

Answer (score 2):

I managed to load "only" ActiveModel validations and it's dependencies, I ended up requiring

```
require 'active_support/concern'
require 'active_model/validator'
require 'active_model/validations'
require 'active_model/naming'
require 'active_model/callbacks'
require 'active_support/callbacks'
require 'active_model/translation
```

just to make this pass:

```
class Foo
  include ActiveModel::Validations
end
```

so it seems I'll be requiring the entire active model or find an alternative validations framework.

Comment: yeah and I needed to require activesupport/concern and couldn't get past a no method error for concerns (despite requiring per example above)

Comment: Good point, activesupport/concern is usually a part of my projects, so I didn't pick that one up! Updated!

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'active_model'


class Account
  include ActiveModel::Validations
end
```